# Adding a video to new page

Tags: javascript, html

I have a script that runs if a button is pressed that creates a new window with a new button. I want to add a video to this page, how can I do that? This is the script that creates the page. Very new to html/javascript sorry if this is a stupid question

```
var w = window.open(''),
    button = w.document.createElement('button');
  button.innerHTML = 'Start Test';

  button.addEventListener('click', function () {
    w.alert('!');
  });

  var container = w.document.createElement('div');
  container.id = 'buttonParent';


  w.document.body.appendChild(container);
  container.appendChild(button);
```

Comment: please don't downvote me, I'm new to this, I don't know why youre downvoting.

Answer (score -1):

You should be able to add this to the page using HTML video tags:

http://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_video.asp